# How can I determine why the following JavaScript code inserts the timer record twice?

Tags: javascript

The following JavaScript code inserts the timer record twice, it's exact duplicate, why is this, and how can I fix it?

We think it's happening at the `onbeforeunload` but I know nothing about JavaScript.

```
    if (typeof(HandleTimerII) === undefined) {
      HandleTimer = {};
    }

    var execCounter;
    execCounter = 0;

    var HandleTimerII = {
      sessionStartPoint: null,
      sessionStartTime: null,
      sessionSavedChange: false,
      sessionUser: null,
      sessionCase: null,
      sessionId: null,
      savecCount: null,
      entityName: null,
      sessionStart: function(formContext) {
        //debugger;
        this.entityName = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName();
        this.sessionStartPoint = Date.now();
        this.sessionStartTime = new Date().toISOString();
        this.sessionCase = {
          Id: Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId(),
          LogicalName: this.entityName
        };
        this.sessionUser = {
          Id: Xrm.Page.context.getUserId(),
          LogicalName: "systemuser"
        };
        this.sessionId = this.generateSessionId();


        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
          if (execCounter === 0) {

            if (HandleTimerII.entityName === "cog_case") HandleTimerII.logSessionToCRM();
          }
          execCounter += 1;
        };

      },

      generateSessionId: function() {
        var S4 = function() {
          return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
        };
        return (S4() + S4() + "-" + S4() + "-" + S4() + "-" + S4() + "-" + S4() + S4() + S4());
      },

      sessionSave: function(formContext) {
        this.sessionSavedChange = true;
      },

      logSessionToCRM: function() {
        debugger;
        //context = HandleTimerII._context;
        var sessionDuration = Math.round((Date.now() - HandleTimerII.sessionStartPoint) / 1000);

        var caseAssigneeRec = {};
        caseAssigneeRec.cog_AssigneeId = HandleTimerII.sessionUser;
        caseAssigneeRec.cog_caseworktime = sessionDuration;
        caseAssigneeRec.cog_Case = HandleTimerII.sessionCase;
        caseAssigneeRec.cog_SavedChanges = HandleTimerII.sessionSavedChange;
        caseAssigneeRec.cog_AssignmentReason = HandleTimerII.sessionId;
        caseAssigneeRec.cog_SessionStart = HandleTimerII.sessionStartTime;
        caseAssigneeRec.cog_SessionEnd = new Date().toISOString();

        XrmServiceToolkit.Rest.Create(
          caseAssigneeRec,
          "cog_caseassigneesSet",
          function(result) {
            caseAsigneeId = result.cog_caseassigneesid;
            console.log("saved assignee record");
          },
          function(error) {
            equal(true, false, error.message);
          },
          true
        );

      }
    };
```